# Regarding Azure Synapse Pipeline, fetch name who have triggerred the pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

There is a scenario in which when a file is uploaded on the Azure Storage DataLake, a trigger is executed in which a series of databrick notebook is run. I want to find a way with which I could fetch the name of the user from which this triggerred is occurred. Is there any way or any Python code that I can write to fetch who have actually executed this pipeline/trigger. It is an event based trigger.